# Trim off N bytes from audio file using SoX / FFmpeg etc, on Windows?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox, audacity, file-recovery

My team accidentally on purpose clicked NO when Audacity asked to save the recording. So I left with bunch of *.au files, after using recovery program.

Some of them did have header and still open-able with audacity itself (example : [this one](https://rinaldojonathan.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/a-113.zip)), and some other are just complete nonsense, sometimes having the header filled with text from random javascript or HTML code (like [this one](https://rinaldojonathan.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/a-9.zip)).  Probably hard disk half overwritten with browser cache? I don't know. And at this point, I almost don't care.

The audacity is on default settings, with sample rate 44100Hz. I can open a-113.au using audacity, from standard open files. I also was able to achieve open files using "Open RAW files" from Audacity, using this settings :

[image]

so I assume header takes 12384 bytes.

Now, how do I trim 12384 bytes from the file when opened as RAW, with either SoX or ffmpeg? because if I open it as RAW with 0 offset (default settings), it will add the header as a noise.

Current ffmpeg command I used : `ffmpeg.exe  -f f32le -ar 44.1k -ac 1 -i  source destination` 
Current sox command I used : `sox -t raw --endian little --rate 44100 -b 1 -b 32 --encoding floating-point  %%A "converted/%%~nxA.wav"` 
Both still have header as a noise in the converted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ffmpeg, use the subfile protocol.

```
ffmpeg.exe  -f f32le -ar 44.1k -ac 1 -start 12384 -i  "subfile:source" destination
```